# Unknow syntax with #define

Tags: c

I clicked the following in main() (This is from LPC17xx interface uSD code)

```
xdev_in(uart0_getc);
```

and I got this

```
#define xdev_in(func) xfunc_in = (unsigned char(*)(void))(func)
```

What does this syntax mean?

```
xfunc_in = (unsigned char(*)(void))(func)
```

Comment: what is the data type of xfunc_in ?

Comment: One line out of context with no other information is difficult to parse. Please [edit] to provide more details. (If you put this single line as-is in a source file and try to compile it, the compiler couldn't parse it either. It would need more context.)

Comment: The above code should give you compilation error. Please check properly

Answer (score 2):

All in all this is what's happening as far as I can tell:

There is a definition:

```
#define xdev_in(func) xfunc_in = (unsigned char(*)(void))(func)
```

The statement:

```
xdev_in(uart0_getc);
```

Is identical to typing:

```
xfunc_in = (unsigned char (*)(void))(uart0_getc);
```

which more than likely means the following:

There is a generic function pointer `xfunc_in` that's used in the code BELOW the `xdev_in(uart0_getc)` statement in some form.  That is being 'pointed to' a function of the form:

```
 unsigned char uart0_getc(void);
```

Now uart0_getc may actually NOT be declared as above it may be a different function, a function pointer or a void * or whatever; but before getting into that let's explain the snippet `unsigned char (*)(void)`

It is a function pointer type (without a variable or type name assigned) that would point to a function of the form unsigned char foo(void); However there is no variable name in that snippet; it's the same as if I was to say type `char` without a variable name.

Now for the `()` outside: That whole snippet is then put inside parentheses `()` to create a typecast to that function pointer type.

And then applied to uart0_getc to typecast uart0_getc value to that function pointer type.

It's the same concept as for example taking one simple type and casting it to another simple type:

```
 int c = (int)'A'; /* type cast character A to an int */
```

However it's being done with function pointers.

If you read up on function pointers you'll understand the syntax.

If you don't know what type casting is then you need to first understand that before looking at function pointer type definitions and typecasts.

Answer (score 1):

The C preprocessor will go through your code and replace the code with that definition before compiling it; it's a so-called *function-like macro*.

The `xdev_in(func)` will be expanded to (replaced with)  `xfunc_in = (unsigned char(*)(void))(func)`.

Note that in the definiton, `func` is a parameter; so your code could be `xdev_in(x)` and it would be replaced with `xfunc_in = (unsigned char(*)(void))(x)`.

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion

Comment: how about this syntax?

xfunc_in = (unsigned char(*)(void))(func)

Comment: You didn't provide any context for where that call comes up. At a guess it's casting something as a pointer.

Comment: It looks like a function pointer rather than a cast, but I'm hopeless with this kind of thing.

Comment: At least please explain clearly what does (unsigned char(*)(void))(func) mean?